# Cannot include standard C++ libraries with MinGW

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, mingw

I have a Qt C++ application that compiles fine with the MSVC compiler. Now I'm trying to compile the same application with MinGW so that I can eventually port it to Mac OSX. However, when doing so I'm getting an error on all the standard includes:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
```

And the compiler outputs:

```
..\trunk\stable.h:29:21: error: algorithm: No such file or directory
..\trunk\stable.h:30:17: error: ctime: No such file or directory
..\trunk\stable.h:31:15: error: map: No such file or directory
..\trunk\stable.h:32:19: error: sstream: No such file or directory
..\trunk\stable.h:33:18: error: vector: No such file or directory
```

I really don't understand what could be causing this issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: Which mingw? mingw32 or mingw32-w64? Did you use the MSys/Mingw32 bundle, the cygwin packages, or did you unzip the files yourself somewhere?

Comment: Are you compiling with g++? C++ files need to be compiled with g++ instead of gcc, generally.

Comment: @JonathanProtzenko, I didn't do any special configuration, I'm using the compiler included with the Qt SDK. As far as I can see from the compilation output, it's mingw32. Probably not the cygwin package since Qt doesn't require it.

Comment: @MichaelSlade, in the compilation output, I first see a line `mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug` then several `gcc -x .....` so maybe that's indeed the problem. Any idea how I can make Qt or mingw32 use g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: What extension do your source files have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the more common errors you will see if your source is C++ but is being compiled as C.

This in turn can happen if the source uses `.C` (note capital C) extension for C++ files.  If the source is used in a case-insensitive file system (like all of the windows ones generally) then `make` probably won't be able to properly tell whether to compile them as C or C++.

By default, `make` (including the mingw version) will compile C++ source from extensions `.C`, `.cc` and `.cpp`.  ([This page](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) has the details).

You have 3 options:

- rename your sources to one of the above extensions.  generally `.cc` and `.cpp` are the easiest to work with.
- if ALL of the sources in the `makefile`, you can go `CC=mingw32-g++ mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug`
- you can add this to the `makefile` or one of the included files:

  ```
  %.o: %.c++
      $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
  ```

  but this will only work if the makefile(s) haven't changed the rules for compilation.